# New user definition (Technically)

Tags: google-analytics, google-play

Can anyone explain the term “New User” in Google Analytics?
If a user un-install the app and later installs the same app on the same device then it will be counted as “New users” or “Repeat users”?
The data for install are showing around 4,000 and only 600 new users are showing in Google analytics reports.